# Github repository listing and file contents in php

Tags: php, github, github-api

Github likes to insert garbage into scripts and break them between the dev and production servers. The github server is remote, and I don't have access to ssh or the commandline for that server. I'm not the one that pushes the scripts to the production server.

The client asked me to programmatically check the files for the "gitmonster" through a php script from the dev server.

Without command line access, is there a way to get file names of each file in a github repository?

Once I have that, is there a way to file_get_contents the contents of the files in that repository?

I had imagined that there would be a URL access method where you pass some token parameters with GET, but I really can't find the documentation that teaches what I'm trying to do. Any help appreciated, even if it's an explanation why github inserts garbage into the scripts.

Comment: `git-ls-files` - Show information about files in the index and the working tree

Comment: I don't have command line access.

Comment: then you could scrape the webpage

Comment: Crawl the contents of a directory that are behind a password? Isn't there the passing of tokens somewhere?

Comment: My thought was that I could do something like file_get_contents or cURL to pass the password. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Isn't cURL command line?

Comment: I mean cURL as a php function. It's built in to php and can be used for posting data remotely and getting the returned output.